# Windows/Ubuntu Dual Install Issue with Intel RST

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

I have a laptop Acer Aspire A515-54G (128GB SSD & 1TB HDD) with windows 10 installed in the SSD. Recently, I needed to install Ubuntu in dual boot, so I shrinked the HDD since it had free space. But Ubuntu installation failed since Intel RST was enabled.

I google the issue and followed this article. Please have a look.

https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/

Following the article, I changed the storage device driver to Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller and then from the BIOS I changed the SATA settings to AHCI. All according the article.

After I completed all the steps from the article, I was able to install Ubuntu. Now, using GRUB menu was shown from which I could choose any of the two OS. When I chose Ubuntu it ran perfectly but Windows wouldn't boot giving the stop code INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE.

After a lot of googling, I was able to run the windows in safe mode from advanced options. My intention was to change the driver setting back.

Here I have these questions:

1. How can I fix my Windows?
2. Should changing the storage driver in safe mode would help in any way? If yes, which one do I select since I dont remember the exact name of the previous ones there are a lot of options within Intel and I do not really want to experiment with them. See the picture below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FdK_r1KTY0SgkXJwTkVlrvvocIqaMcsa/view?usp=drivesdk

I would be extremely grateful for your help.

Comment: These "articles" are all wrong. RST is perfectly supported on Ubuntu, but you need to assemble raid before you install Ubuntu using mdadm instead of disabling RST. Enable RST back and Windows should load.

Comment: Thanks A LOT for replying! Please let me know:
**1.** Will changing AHCI back to RAID in BIOS will affect Ubuntu? Ubuntu is installed on the HDD and Windows was installed on SSD.

**2.** Should I do anything about the storage driver change?

Comment: Windows should work, but Ubuntu may need some configuration to use raid, or reinstallation.

Comment: I changed SATA setting from AHCI to RST in BIOS. It still gives blue screen with stop code Inaccesible boot device

Comment: Also, if there is no other option I would prefer reinstalling Ubuntu rather than Windows which have softwares installed on it.

Comment: It seems that you broke something in Wundows already. I can't help with that.

Comment: @Pilot6 What do you propose I should do now?

Comment: Try to restore Windows settings how they were before.

Comment: Can you help me do that since I did not save a restore point in the start. I was unaware of restore points.

Comment: I don't use Windows and I can't help  with that.

Comment: Grub will not boot hibernated Windows, and fast start up sets hibernation flag. So fast start up must be off in Windows and Windows turns it back on with some updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @oldfred That was it!
I don't know how to thank you, man! I have been trying to resolve this issue for 2 days now, you finally solved my problem. Windows booted just fine, after I disabled fast boot.

Comment: @oldfred One more thing, should I change SATA settings from AHCI to the original RST?

Comment: Then Ubuntu would not work. Do not know if RAID drivers would then work or not. I would leave as AHCI. But you should plan good backup policy for both Windows & Ubuntu's data and configuration.