# Intel RST isssue while installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows, rst

**Machine information**

- Acer predator Helios 300
- 256 GB SSD - Windows installed
- 1 TB   HDD - Free space

I have to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as a dual boot  on the 1 TB HDD of the machine. While trying to install , got the RST issue.

```
This computer uses Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology). You need to turn off RST before installing Ubuntu. For instructions, open this page: help.ubuntu.com/rst
```

Found some links regarding the same issue , but lots of them lost their original windows version while following their steps. I don't want to lose original windows version.

existing links :

1. [Disable RST for Installing ubuntu 20.4 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281127/disable-rst-for-installing-ubuntu-20-4-dual-boot)
2. [Workaround to Install Ubuntu 20.04 with Intel RST systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems)
3. [Windows/Ubuntu Dual Install Issue with Intel RST](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260366/windows-ubuntu-dual-install-issue-with-intel-rst)

How to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as a dual boot without losing the windows original version? Highly appreciated if anyone comes up with step by step solution for this issue.

Comment: There is no generic step by step solution. It depends on a way how Windows is installed, etc. Don't expect a guaranteed solution.

Comment: I have mentioned that windows installed in 256GB SSD and i want to install ubuntu on 1 TB HDD. What do you meant by ' It depends on a way how Windows is installed'?

Comment: There may be lots of raid configurations in Windows. Anyway there is no 100% solution. Ubuntu works well with RST enabled, but getting it work in dual boot with Windows is tricky.

Comment: The existing links, #1 and #2, Choice #2, seems to work well for most folks. Link #3 seems to break stuff.

Comment: @Pilot6 re: *"Ubuntu works well with RST enabled"*... how can this be if the Ubuntu installer won't get past RST?

Comment: I recently installed Ubuntu on a laptop with RST enabled that didn't have Windows. I noticed RST only after I installed it. No problems at all. The problem is when you install on some sort of raid configured by Windows.